# Select text from a list view when that is cliked C# Metro App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have a list view which I populate it from an API.. I want it fill a text box with the value which is found in the text block when I click..

My Listview...

```
<ListView Width="300" Height="134" x:Name="lsvObjectives" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsObjectives}}" ItemClick="lsvObjectives_ItemClick">
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="left"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-7"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="310" Height="33" Background="#FFE9D5F0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                <StackPanel Width="270" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,0,0">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding objective}" Style="{StaticResource ContentTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="13"/>
                                                </StackPanel>                                               
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
```

This is how I populate the list:

```
 private async void getObjectives()
         {
             string getObjectives = baseAddress + "unitPlansDetailsByUnit/1";
             var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(getObjectives));
             objectivesHelper data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objectivesHelper>(content);
             foreach (var item in data.result)
             {
                 cvsObjectives.Source = data.result;
             }

         }
```

My Classes:

```
 public class objectives
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string objective { get; set; }
    }
    class objectivesHelper
    {
        public List<objectives> result { get; set; }
    }
```

I am unable to read the value from the text block which is found in my list view..

Someone kindly help me do this..
Any kind of help is appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the value in your **lsvObjectives_ItemClick** method by casting the [ItemClickEventArgs.ClickedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemclickeventargs) to your type **objectives**.

For example:

```
private void lsvObjectives_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    objectives item = e.ClickedItem as objectives;
    var itemText = item.objective;

    youtTextBox.Text = item.Description.ToString();
}
```